# Extra low priority processes in linux?

Tags: linux, process, priority, nice

On Linux processes have "nice" values ranging from -20 to 19. I wish I could assign even lower priority like 100 so that "background work" will yield as much as possible to other process but still enjoy all remaining CPU time. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of cgroups for that one really low priority process. You can create a cgroup just for that one process (call it `lowprio` or w/e) and use the `cpu.shares` parameter to only allow it a certain share of CPU time. You can read more about this approach in, e.g., RHEL's [Resource Management Guide](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Resource_Management_Guide/index.html#sect-cfs).